# Perl (use CGI) Can't call method "header" without a package or object reference

Tags: perl, oop, cgi

Alright, using Perl for the first time in a decade, sort of rusty.  Thinking perhaps some updates since then (genius huh?)

Alrighty, This is Perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 x86_64-linux-thread-multi with 29 registered patches on AWS micro.

Perl came with it, I just yum installed perl-CGI perl-Data-Dumper

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;                                        # load cgi routines
my $q = CGI>new;                                # cgi object
print   $q->header(),
        $q->start_html("Hello World"),
        $q->h1('Hello'),
        $q->end_html;
~
```

Seems about a simple and straightforward as it can be, as I build programs bit by bit.  But I have got an error at if I run it at the command line (or browser).

> Can't call method "header" without a package or object reference at create line 4.

Line 4 is the print $q->header();  "create" is the file name.

Any ideas?  Bring me up to date in Perl 2017?  My problems, being rusty are always something fabulously simple.

Comment: "Bring me up to date in Perl 2017? " — `use strict; use warnings;` (well, that's Perl 2000 although it holds true in 2017) & https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE

Comment: @Quentin: The point about CGI being removed from the core is moot. He's using a Red Hat version of Linux, so it's not included anyway.

Comment: if CGI has been removed, is there a better library?  I'm not so attached to CGI, I had html libraries of my own.

Comment: CGI still works. And, as you've seen, you can easily install the module even when it's not part of your standard installation. But please don't use the HTML generation functions in CGI.pm. Far better to use a [templating system](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) to separate your HTML from your code. If you want to go further down the road of Modern Perl Web Dev, then start by reading [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

Comment: Excellent, should I use CGI for PUSH and GET then?  You said not for HTML generation, so I query what should it be used for.

Comment: Perhaps some confusion over two similar terms here. **CGI** is a web protocol that defines the interaction between a web server and programs that generate dynamic content. **CGI,pm** is a Perl module which helps to you write programs that use that protocol. Unfortunately, CGI.pm also contains unrelated stuff like content generation. I'm saying use CGI.pm for the CGI parts of your program (accessing the various types of input, producing the CGI headers) and use other, better, tools for the content generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a typo.

```
my $q = CGI>new;
```

should probably be

```
my $q = CGI->new;
```

Perl is interpreting your code as:

```
my $q = 'CGI' > 'new';
```

So you end up with a false value (probably an empty string) in `$q`. And you can't call methods on an empty string :-)

Comment: and yes it is.  DANG! and thanks.. that took me two hours before posting.

Comment: thanks, I knew I'd feel simple.   Now got a permission denied from webserver, though this is a different question.

Comment: I should delete this question shouldn't I ... thanks though.

Comment: Ah, an undeletable example of my occasional simplicity.

Comment: no worries, was a chmod on the file, everything is peachy keen, thanks again.